# Custom table query in SQL Server similar to custom table in SPSS?

Tags: sql, sql-server

From the sample data it will compute the average price per name and code including the combinations for all names and all codes.

[image: Sample Data]

[image: Sample Output]

Currently I'm using the `union all` for all the combinations which is a tedious way. Is there a simplest way to query that case?

```
SELECT NAME ,CODE, AVG(PRICE)
FROM SAMPLE_DATA
GROUP BY
NAME ,CODE

UNION ALL
SELECT 'ALL NAMES' ,CODE, AVG(PRICE)
FROM SAMPLE_DATA
GROUP BY
CODE

UNION ALL
SELECT NAME, 'ALL CODES', AVG(PRICE)
FROM SAMPLE_DATA
GROUP BY NAME

UNION ALL
SELECT 'ALL NAMES', 'ALL CODES, AVG(PRICE)
FROM SAMPLE_DATA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GROUPING SETS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT NAME, CODE, AVG(PRICE)
FROM SAMPLE_DATA
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (NAME, CODE), (NAME), (CODE), () )
```

Just include all the combinations you want in the list.